# Android Camera: Save preview frames to buffer?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I would like to use onPreviewFrame to save a predefined number of frames into buffer and later save them as png's.

There are many examples on how to do the whole capturing and saving in one go, but I need to do just the buffering of, let's say 3 consecutive frames first. Perhaps I could create an array of byte objects? I am new to java so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case of out of memory, you have to limit your array size

```
    private ArrayList<byte[]> queue = new ArrayList<byte[]>(3);
    private Camera.PreviewCallback mPreviewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {        
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (queue.size() == 3) {
                queue.remove(0);
            }
            queue.add(data);
        }

    };
```

Comment: Definitely, array size will be limited to prevent out of memory. Thanks for the hint, gonna try it now

Comment: if you you wanna dump the data in other thread simultaneously, don't forget to add synchronized (queue){} to cover the code block

Comment: saving can be done offline, after I've captured the frames into Array. I still have to figure out though how to do that...

Comment: Also, could you explain why `if(queue.size() == 3) {             queue.remove(0);` is needed?

Comment: that means your buffer queue is full. if you wanna a new data, and don't wanna overflow, you have to remove an old data first